# bundle install: 'minitest/autorun x64-mingw32' not in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

When trying to run `bundle install` on i receive the following exception:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'minitest/autorun x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile.
```

I was originally trying to run `bundle exec rake`, which suggests the same issue with `gem 'minitest/autorun x64-mingw32'`. Running them with `rake test` works fine; hence, I think I've done something wrong with bundler related to my OS (windows 7 x64). The install works properly without this package. I also tried using `unit/test` with the same result.

Ruby version is 2.4.4.

**Gemfile:**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gemspec


gem 'json', '~> 2.1.0', '>= 2.0.4'
gem 'addressable', '~> 2.5.2', '>= 2.5.2'
gem 'mongo', '~> 2.5.1', '>= 2.5.1'

group :test do
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'minitest/autorun'
end
```

Do I need to specify the platform or some other variable so that bundle looks for the right version of the gem on rubygems?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `gem 'minitest/autorun'` - no gem with name `minitest/autorun`. Change that to `gem 'minitest'`

Comment: @Leo ah damnit. Thanks dude, working now. Appreciate the help.